# Google-Schemas: Sender Image

Tags: microdata, google-schemas

How do I get my G+ profile/logo to display as the sender image in Gmail's new grid view?

I added the Google-Schema markup to my emails. When I test my email, the 'featured image' is displaying properly but I can't get the 'sender image' to display. What am I missing?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
  <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Restaurant.com"/>
    <link itemprop="url" href="http://www.restaurant.com/"/>
    <link itemprop="url/googlePlus" href="https://plus.google.com/+restaurantcom/posts"/>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="about" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <link itemprop="image" href=“http://image.exct.net/lib/feef1377736103/m/1/0328-mi1-mobile-v1.jpg”/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the DKIM domain matching the domain from the Google+ page you are linking (i.e. restaurant.com) and is the Google+ page verified?
These are the requirements for the company logo to show up.

Comment: It is not matching. We were trying to avoid changing our DKIM domain.